# Using genisoimage with less status messages

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that does several things.  One of which is to use genisoimage to create an iso for a bluray.  It gives annoying status messages like this:

```
 26.13% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:54 2012
 26.17% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:51 2012
 26.22% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:52 2012
 26.26% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:53 2012
 26.31% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:55 2012
 26.35% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:52 2012
 26.40% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:53 2012
 26.45% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:54 2012
 26.49% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:51 2012
 26.54% done, estimate finish Mon Dec 24 12:31:52 2012
```

These messages do not help me.  Is there an easy way to turn off these messages?

Comment: use -quiet switch. if that doesn't help then redirect everything to /dev/null. i.e. "&> /dev/null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to search the manpage of `genisoimage`?

`-quiet This  makes  genisoimage  even less verbose.  No progress output
              will be provided.`

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was looking all over the man page but just got lost in all the options.  This worked perfectly.

Comment: No need to look all over it. Type the `/` key to search for things like "verbose", "quiet" or "silent".